# White label for angular 2 project

Tags: angular, white-labelling

I have an Angular 2 application and I need to create a white label project based on the that. In the white label I need to alter some of the components css and also add new routes / new components. What is the recommended way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

I would

- create an Angular library (see https://medium.com/@tomsu/how-to-build-a-library-for-angular-apps-4f9b38b0ed11),
- define the style parts that can be overwritten by a white-labelled consumer in a global stylesheet in the library (as opposed to in each and every individual component),
- overwrite these parts in the white-labelled consumer applications,
- export all relevant components (and a Routing Module) from the library,
- import the routes and the components to the consumers, and add additional specific routes/components on top of that.